# Can latest version VSCode debug C++ with C++ extension and MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

After updating VSC to new version(1.58.0), it nether InternalConsole nor ExternalConsole can run .EXE file automatically which is compiled successfully by cl.exe. I have configured the .JSON file while it worked well for previous version VSC. The JSON file code is below.

```
// lauch.json
"version": "0.2.0",
"symbolsearchpath": "https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "cl.exe build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "console":"externalTerminal",
        "preLaunchTask": "cl.exe build active file"
    }
]
// task.json
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "cl.exe build active file",
        "command": "cl.exe",
        "args": [
            "/Zi",
            "/EHsc",
            "/Fe:",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "${file}"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": ["$msCompile"],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

After pressing F5, VSC could compile the C++ project but cannot run or debug even I submit some breakpoints.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what happens when you try to run your program? Is there an error? Have you checked the various output windows for errors?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have solved this question which is caused by Windows Debugger not installing. I try to debug or run my program before the extension (Windows Debugger) installing completely and this problem would be encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. When user try to run or debug their program this question which VSC could not run .EXE file automatically will encounter before the extension of VSC (Windows debugger C++) not installing completely. After updating VSC, please wait for its installing completely.
For more C++ compiler configuration on VSC
MSVC
**https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc**
g++
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw